# How can I execute a class.cs file inside a batch file

Tags: c#, class, batch-file

I am running a batch file (included below). Is there a way I can include file class.cs (C# class) in between the two commands inside the .bat file?

```
echo off
set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%
set CUR_HH=%time:~0,2%
if %CUR_HH% lss 10 (set CUR_HH=0%time:~1,1%)

set CUR_NN=%time:~3,2%
set CUR_SS=%time:~6,2%
set CUR_MS=%time:~9,2%

set SUBFILENAME=%CUR_YYYY%%CUR_MM%%CUR_DD%-%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%%CUR_SS%

(py tool.py -p COM8 write_flash 0x20200 diags_0.0.15.bin 
py tool.py -p COM8 write_flash 0x1c0088 diags_0.0.15.bin) > log_%SUBFILENAME%.txt
```

I want to try something as mentioned below:

```
echo off
set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%
set CUR_HH=%time:~0,2%
if %CUR_HH% lss 10 (set CUR_HH=0%time:~1,1%)

set CUR_NN=%time:~3,2%
set CUR_SS=%time:~6,2%
set CUR_MS=%time:~9,2%

set SUBFILENAME=%CUR_YYYY%%CUR_MM%%CUR_DD%-%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%%CUR_SS%

(py tool.py -p COM8 write_flash 0x20200 diags_0.0.15.bin
echo class.cs 
py tool.py -p COM8 write_flash 0x1c0088 diags_0.0.15.bin) > log_%SUBFILENAME%.txt
```

Comment: Compile the file to an executable and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "Class.cs" has a `Main` method. You could do this:

`powershell -command "(Add-Type -Path .\class.cs -PassThru)::Main()"`

Comment: add this to the batch file?

Comment: Yes, instead of `echo class.cs`